# Delphi Using a 2d array defined by static array

Tags: arrays, delphi

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  StaticArray = Array[0..1000] of Double;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  DArray: Array of StaticArray;
  Length : Integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Length:=5;
 Setlength(DArray, Length);
end;

end.
```

When I try to use Setlength() to define the length of the 2DArray it gives me no error or nothing.

I expect the result to be an array with 1000 Column and Length amount of Rows.
However the Result is just 1 row with 1001 columns.

Any idea why?

I need the Array to be defined this way but I'm stuck on how to set the length of it.

*Edit number of columns, 0..1000 which adds up to 1001 columns.

*Edit2 Fixed the code a bit more.

*Edit3 Made a better example

Comment: StaticArray has 1001 elements, not 1000, FWIW. And yes, 2DArray is 2D, 1001 * Length. You didn't show anywhere near enough code for us to diagnose your problem.  We need a [mcve].

Comment: It works fine for me in Delphi Berlin, with the exception of the extra element that David mentioned. A 10-line console app that does a WriteLn of Length(MyArray) and Length(MyArray[10]) shows that they both exist and have the appropriate values.

Comment: Why don't you post your real code first? The above doesn't compile. `Length` is not declared or assigned anywhere, and the declaration of `StaticArray` is wrong too.

Comment: `2DArray` is not valid identificator, so code still is fake

Comment: How do you know DArray has just 1 row? You're not reading it anywhere

Comment: I used the Debug tool to examine the Array. There it states it is a 1x1000 Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code, intentionally left the same id `Length`. Code works as expected:

```
procedure TForm1.Button20Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  StaticArray = Array[0..1000] of Double;
var
  DArray: Array of StaticArray;
  Length : Integer;
begin
  Length := 5;
  SetLength(DArray, Length);
  Caption := IntToStr(High(DArray)); //ouputs 4

  //note bad usage of Length var, so we can not use Length intrinsic function

  DArray[3, 1000] := 42;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you MBo for taking your time to look into this. The code looks fine.
I think it is my debugger inspector that give me the wrong indication of the Array size.
See this [picture](https://i.imgur.com/fvyxlCl.png). When I hover my mouse over it, it displays the 5 rows properly.

Comment: Note that `Complete, and Verifiable example` from you could help to solve the problem very fast. And please avoid using `Length` identificator - it is very important intrinsic function (but unfortunately it's name is not reserved).

Comment: While Length hides the Length() function, you still access the latter as System.Length().